# Click on a button that is moved when an input loses focus is not registered

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I encountered a weird problem while creating a form with React (it is most likely not specific to React however). The form consists of an input, an error hint underneath it and a button, all vertically stacked. The input is focused on component mount, and the error hint might appear when the user clicks outside of the input. When the input is focused and the user tries to click the button, it loses the focus which may cause the hint to appear. The hint pushes the button downwards which prevents the button's click event from registering, resulting in a bad user experience.

Is there a way force the button to get clicked before the input loses focus?

I have replicated this situation here: https://jsfiddle.net/tacticalteapot/b40hLv3c/4/

Code from the fiddle:

```
function App() {
  const ref = React.useRef(null);
  const [showLabel, setShowLabel] = React.useState(false);
  const [clicked, setClicked] = React.useState(false);
 
  React.useEffect(() => {
    ref.current.focus();
  }, []);
  
  return (
  <div>
    <input ref={ref} onBlur={() => setShowLabel(true)} />
    <div>
      {showLabel && <label>a label appeared that moved the button</label>}
    </div>
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setClicked(true)}>
        CLICK ME
      </button>
    </div>
    {clicked && <h6 style={{color: 'red'}}>CLICKED</h6>}
  </div>)
}
```

Comment: It's not that the button "moves" but rather that your component re-renders due to state changes.

Comment: The reason is: the input must be focused when a user enters the form. The error hint underneath appears when the input loses focus and the value entered is incorrect or absent (this is managed by final-form). The button resends an sms code (it's a phone number confirmation form). The user might enter the form and if the code never arrives he might want to click that button. If the input is focused (as it should be when te form is first rendered) and the user tries to click the resend button, the click fails to register as shown in the question. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Another thing is, if you move the button in such a way that its position is not affected by the hint in any way, the click registers as expected (e.g. move the button to be inline with the input in the above example). So I don't think it is an issue with component re-renders.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. You're moving the button down by rendering an error message and you're worried about the cx because the button has moved. But if the error is shown no-one should be able to click the button in the first place no? And if that move is the issue why not show the error message without moving the button?

Comment: No, the button that is moved is not a submit button, as I said, that is a phone confirmation form, and the user is free to click the button in question at any time (it resends the code in case it does not arrive, it does not submit the form, the submit button is irrevelant here). The resend button moves when the error hint appears escaping the cursor. I hope that clears things up.

Comment: So make it not move then...?!

Comment: lmao, I have thought of that, the design choices are not up to me, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of the order of events. `onBlur` fires first which immediately shows the label. The `<label>` is rendered directly "on top" of the button. Your click event never registers. To test this, try setting height for your label or even wrap it in another container with a height. Alternatively, add padding to your button such that it's not fully covered by the `<label>` - it'll register.

Obviously there are better styling methods for this.

```js
function App() {
  const ref = React.useRef(null);
  const [showLabel, setShowLabel] = React.useState(false);
  const [clicked, setClicked] = React.useState(false);
 
  React.useEffect(() => {
    ref.current.focus();
  }, []);
  
  handleClick = () => {
  setClicked(true);
  }
  
  return (
  <div>
    <input ref={ref} onBlur={() => setShowLabel(true)} />
    <div className="test">
      {showLabel && <label>a label appeared that moved the button</label>}
    </div>
    <div>
      <button style={{padding: "30px"}} onClick={() => handleClick()}>
        CLICK ME
      </button>
    </div>
    {clicked && <h6 style={{color: 'red'}}>CLICKED</h6>}
  </div>)
}


ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: This seems like the only solution, I thought there might be a magical way to change the order of events somehow.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a problem with focus. Try using `Tab`, button gets focused correctly.
Problem is with the UX itself and how the page is pushed down by validation messages.

It would be the best to change the UX slightly to allow the space for validation errors without pushing any elements below:

https://jsfiddle.net/eucj04np/5/

Also, remember to add `aria-describedby` that points to the id of the element with error validation message. This will help assistive technologies to read out the error content once element is focused.